# Doctrine2 Entities with bitmasked columns

Tags: symfony1, doctrine-orm

I'm working on a project which has entities which have multiple bitmask columns.  So for example my User entity has a column `specialitiesBitmask`.  This bitmask will correlate to another table, for example, Specialty.  If I wanted to do be able to do something like `$user->getSpecialties()` what is the best way to do this?  I'd need to query Specialty table, and break down bitmask accordingly.  However with Doctrine2 you don't have access to the EntityManager.

I looked around for any solutions, but couldn't find much.  Looking at this you could use a listener to hook the postLoad event and get the EM that way, however that is pretty hacky and not clean.

The only other solution I could think of would be to create other services and do something like `$userService->getSpecialtiesForUser($user);` however that is going to also not be that clean/efficient as there are a number of columns which are bitmasked.

What do you think is the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `SpecialtyRepository`, and implement `getByUser($user)`. You can find how to do so [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#custom-repository-classes) and [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html).

Then, to get the specialities of a user, you'd do:

`$specialties = $em->getRepository('Specialty')->getByUser($user);`

Comment: Right, thought about doing it that way.  In my example I use the $userService instead as a proxy to get to all the other specialities/etc. since there is likely to be 5-10 of these on an object and it'd be a pain to get all those services each time.

Comment: There's has to be a balance between RAD (rapid application development) and flexibility ...